# dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("username") from file database.properties returns host user name

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc

I have a simple dataSource() method to set datasource in Spring MVC using JDBC for PostgreSQL. I read database configuration from the resources.database.properties file. But it cannot read database username.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("driver")));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("username")); // - returns host username
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("password"));

    return dataSource;
}
```

The resources.database.properties contains this:

```
driver=org.postgresql.Driver 
url=jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.2:5432/first_db
username=postgres
password=mypassword
```

If I hardcode the user name it works fine.

I just need to get my PostgreSQL user name (witch is running on my Docker container). What is wrong with this?

Comment: What are you doing to get your database.properties file parsed and put into the environment?

Comment: Nothing. It works automatically. It is normal practice to keep static data, such as database configuration, in files like database.configuration. The IDE takes it and even automatically highlights the fields in the file, which means it sees them.

Answer (score 0):

So there is a collision with another environment variable, "username". So you either rename the "username" in the properties or, even better, you can use a namespace:

```
database.driver=org.postgresql.Driver 
database.url=jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.2:5432/first_db
database.username=postgres
database.password=mypassword
```

```java
Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("database.driver")));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("database.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("database.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("database.password"));

    return dataSource;
```

Comment: Yes! It helped! Only after renaming ALL the fields it could detect the right parameter. And the interesting fact is that renaming only one (username) field did not help. And it confused me. That is why I had to write this post. So, Thank you very much @Cristian !